# C# .NET Projects cannot get DLLs from a path which specified at environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

I cloned a solution from Git to my computer. For this solution, we use a SDK. This SDK is placed at the same path in all of contributors computers. I cannot build projects which have assembly references, they are failing to get that files and create classes from that reference. They are using the SDK. Project's assembly references gets its DLLs from a common path which is specified at the environment variable.
Projects are written in .NET 5.
Code is like below;

```
<Reference Include="MyDLL">
         <HintPath>$(MYSDK)\bin\MyDLL.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and error list is filled errors like below;

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Engine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```